# Where is the document returned by MongoDB `updateOne()` actually documented?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The [MongoDB documentation for updateOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) mentions:

> Returns:  A document containing:
>
> - A boolean `acknowledged` as true if the operation ran with write concern
>     or false if write concern was disabled
> - `matchedCount` containing the number of matched documents
> - `modifiedCount` containing the number of modified documents
> - `upsertedId` containing the _id for the upserted
>     document

The document returned by `var document = await db.collection(collectionName).updateOne()` does not resemble the above at all:

```
{
    "n": 1,
    "nModified": 1,
    "opTime": {
        "ts": "6677868873271738369",
        "t": 2
    },
    "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000002",
    "ok": 1,
    "operationTime": "6677868873271738369",
    "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": "6677868873271738369",
        "signature": {
        "hash": "FoBe2OKGcrvuw0yc54BJ0WcOsmI=",
        "keyId": "6673465299137724417"
        }
    }
}
```

There are a number of issues with the returned document:

- The fields in the document include minified names like `n` which don't make sense and don't appear to be documented
- There are no links in the `updateOne` docs to a full description of the format of document and it's fields.
- `JSON.stringify()` on both `document` and `document.result` returne the same thing.

Where is the document returned by `updateOne()` actually documented?

Comment: The "JSON stringified" response from `updateOne()` looks like what you posted. But if you test the actual object returned in response, then you will find that `matchedCount`, `modifiedCount` etc ( all the things actually documented ) are actually there. Because they are implemented as JavaScript Functions, and therefore do not appear in the "stringified" representation of the object.

Comment: Also, NodeJS documentation is here [`updateOne()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#updateOne) as is [the response information](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#~updateWriteOpResult). The "shell documentation" you linked to in the question is *slightly* different to the NodeJS API. But not by much since those `functions` are still named the same in the response object.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you. I missed the small 'shell documentation' and couldn't see links to pick docs for a different client library (like eg, Stripe or any other modern API) - also the docs are offsite which is odd. Anyway, if you consolidate these responses into an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As @neillunn mentioned in his comment, mongodb.com does not have documentation for the node driver. The documentation on mongodb.com is for the JavaScript shell driver.

[Official documentation for the `mongodb` node module is hosted on GitHub](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#~updateWriteOpResult)

Additionally **`matchedCount`, `modifiedCount` etc are getter functions and will not appear in the JSON stringified response**. However they do exist:

```
console.log(`Inserted ${dbResponse.upsertedCount} docs, modified ${dbResponse.modifiedCount}`)
```

Descriptions of [the minified fields is at GitHub](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#~updateWriteOpResult)

Additonally `upsertedCount` is named incorrectly as it does not include updates, it only includes inserted documents.

(Neil post your own answer if you like and I'll mark it as correct)